# log of summation - what to do when the magnitude of terms is unknown?

Tags: logarithms

I know that ln(a+b) can be rewritten as ln(a) + ln(1+b/a) as long as a>c.

Does this last requirement, which I don't really understand, prevent the use of such a tool in working out an equation that will be used across timeseries data (or say in a model), when it is generally unknown at any one timestep (that the equation is applied) whether a or c is greater?

For example, suppose I have this equation:

X = ln (R / (tan theta))

But then I realize that R really should be represented as R = l + p,  and I use this equation to make estimates of x for each timestep where I receive a new l and p value.  Problem is, I never know for sure, at each timestep, whether  l or p is larger.  And I need to take this equation and substitute it into other equations, in hope of simplifying two different equations - it seems not knowing in the future, when the resulting "simplified equations" are applied presents simplification from progressing.

Comment: You can use $\log(a+b)=\log a+\log(1+(b/a))$ as long as $a>0$ and $a+b>0$ --- those are the only requirements.

Comment: Can you link to proof or verification of that?

Comment: The logarithm is defined for all and only positive values of the argument. Since you have a $\log a$ in your formula, you must have $a>0$. Since you have a $\log(a+b)$ in your formula, you must have $a+b>0$. Since $1+(b/a)=(a+b)/a$, it follows that $1+(b/a)>0$, so we don't need to specify that separately. And $\log x+\log y=\log xy$ for all positive $x,y$. These are the basic properties of logarithms. You'll find them in thousands of textbooks, and on thousands of websites. It shouldn't be hard to find a link.

Comment: So, are we OK now?

Comment: Yes, we are. I'd love to mark your comment as the correct answer, but I don't believe that is a possibility.

Comment: What you can do instead is write up and post an answer yourself, now that you understand what's up. Then, later, you can accept your own answer. May seem weird, but it's encouraged here.